# error TS6046: Argument for '--jsx' option must be: 'preserve', 'react-native', 'react'

Tags: reactjs, npm

On my PC I'm not able to compile a ReactJs project that runs smoothly on another PC.

I can't understand where the issue is.

```
react-scripts start

error TS6046: Argument for '--jsx' option must be: 'preserve', 'react-native', 'react'.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template@2.6.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template@2.6.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-20T17_20_33_546Z-debug.log
```

and the file contains the following:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.9
3 info using node@v14.15.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle @coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template@2.6.0~prestart: @coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template@2.6.0
6 info lifecycle @coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template@2.6.0~start: @coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template@2.6.0
7 verbose lifecycle @coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template@2.6.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
10 silly lifecycle @coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template@2.6.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle @coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template@2.6.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template@2.6.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: @coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template@2.6.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid @coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template@2.6.0
15 verbose cwd E:\Projects\PrimaryX-FrontEnd
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19041
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v14.15.3
19 verbose npm  v6.14.9
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template@2.6.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template@2.6.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Any clue how and what to fix?

Comment: Does your project have a tsconfig?  Did you install the node modules?

Comment: @SethLutske Yes at both questions

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are using a recent version of NODEJS in an old project.
You can downgrade your nodejs or update the webpack